# A blue window pops up randomly while using my laptop, it says windows power shell, should I suspect someone hacked into my laptop?

Tags: windows, powershell

While I'm using my computer a blue window will pop up for a second then go away. The label said windows power shell, I've tried looking at the event viewer but I could not identify anything there since I'm a new user. What could be causing this?

Running windows 10

Comment: Take a look into Task Scheduler to see if any programs you have installed is maybe trying to run something periodically. Does the window appear in regular intervals, or maybe when you perform a certain action, or on windows start etc?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes installed programs open up command prompts to run services/init tasks, so its not completely unusual.

I've never seen it happen with powershell however.

it could be innocent and just a program you have installed running init behavior, but it could also be malicious.

the first thing to try is checking what programs are set to startup automatically. if there is a load of bloat, you could try turning off the unnecessary ones and see if it still happens.

but realistically the only real way forward is to get a good quality antivirus, and run a full system scan over your pc to double check. it wont give you 100% certainly as things could possibly get passed it, but realistically if it passes you should be fine